# Devexpress Xtraraports

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

When trying to open the designer I see
[the message as on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxXnx.png)

How can I see the designer again? I tried reopening it but I see the same thing.

Comment: It looks as if you're opening the resource file (.resx) FisaCount.resx, not the designer (.designer.cs) file FisaCount.designer.cs.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with the same thing.
**Check in the codebehind .cs** **the query for your sqlDatasource2** that automatically generates the .cs and check that there are no line breaks and that it has generated symbols such as &, **if they appear delete them** and try to reload the designer again